# Selection of rows by specific coordinates-based rules with dplyr and DBI

Tags: r, dplyr

In my created example:

```
# Packages
library(dplyr)
library(DBI)

# Create myds
ID<-c(1,2,3,4,5)
x<-c(-51.6422,-51.6351,-51.6351,-51.6351,-51.6422)
y<-c(-30.1412,-30.1206,-30.1206,-30.1207,-30.1412)
date<-c("2021-11-01","2021-11-01","2021-11-15", "2021-11-15","2021-11-15")
myds<-data.frame(ID=ID,x=x,y=y,date=as.Date(date))
con <- DBI::dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), ":memory:")
DBI::dbWriteTable(con, "myds", myds)

# Take the table created inside `RSQLite::SQLite()` 
dataset <- dplyr::tbl(con, "myds")

# Rows selection by the rule
sel_vars <- dataset %>% dplyr::??? %>% collect()
```

`???`   Here I'd like to make the rows selection and create a new object (`sel_vars`) with two conditions:

1. Take the row just only if `x` and `y` with no repetition (duplicates) in coordinates, but when I have coincident or duplicates coordinates:
2. I take the coincident coordinates too just only if I have 10 meters neighbourhood row increase in any direction eg. horizontally, vertically, or diagonally (0.00015 or -0.00015 unit in `x` or `y`, like chess king's movement) during the time (`date`).

My desirable output is:

```
sel_vars
    ID x       y        date
[1] 2 -51.6351 -30.1206 2021-11-01
[2] 3 -51.6351 -30.1206 2021-11-15
[3] 4 -51.6351 -30.1207 2021-11-15
```

Please,  any help with it?

Comment: At least for (1) -- I think `dplyr::distinct(ID, x, y, .keep_all = TRUE)` should address that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# Rows selection by the rule, not dlpyr-verbs directly but work:

# function for duplicate detection
exists_duplicate <- function(x,y,date,dates,df,dir = 1){
  #dir is either -1 for the previous, or 1 for the next date
  if (!dir %in% c(-1,1)){
    stop("dir must be -1 or 1")
  }
  # choose either next or previous date depending on dir
  next_date <- dates[which(date == dates) + dir] 
  # exception for dir == -1 and date == min(dates)
  if (length(next_date) == 0){
    return(NA)
  } 

  # exception for dir == 1 and date == max(dates)
  if (is.na(next_date)){
    return(NA)
  }
  n_dupl <-
  df %>% 
    filter(date == !!next_date,
           x == !!x,
           y == !!y) %>%
    nrow()
  n_dupl > 0 # if there are any duplicates, returns TRUE
}


# function for neighbor detection

exists_neighbor <- function(x,y,date,dates,df,dir = 1){
  # dir is either 1 for the next date or 0 for the current date
  if(!(dir %in% c(1,0))){
    stop("dir must be 1 or 0")
  }
  next_date <- dates[which(date == dates) + dir] 
  # exception for dir == 1 and date == max(dates)
  if (is.na(next_date)){
    return(NA)
  }

  n_neighbor <-
    df %>% 
    filter(date == !!next_date,
           abs(x - !! x) <= 0.00015,
           abs(y - !! y) <= 0.00015,
           !(x == !!x & y == !!y)
    ) %>%
    nrow()
  n_neighbor > 0  # if there are any neighbors, returns TRUE
}
data_collected <- dataset %>% collect() 

dates <- dataset %>%
  pull(date) %>%
  unique() %>%
  sort()

data_neighbor <- 
  data_collected %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(has_duplicate = exists_duplicate(x, y, date, !!dates, ., dir = 1)) %>%
  mutate(has_neighbor =   exists_neighbor(x, y, date, !!dates, ., dir = 1)) %>%
  mutate(is_duplicate =  exists_duplicate(x, y, date, !!dates, ., dir = -1)) %>%
  mutate(is_neighbor =    exists_neighbor(x, y, date, !!dates, ., dir = 0))

data_neighbor %>%
  filter(has_duplicate == FALSE | # if there are no duplicates
         has_neighbor == TRUE |   # if there is a neighbor at date == date + 1
         is_neighbor == TRUE      # if there is a neighbor at date == date
  )
# A tibble: 3 x 8
# Rowwise: 
#     ID     x     y  date has_duplicate has_neighbor is_duplicate is_neighbor
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <lgl>         <lgl>        <lgl>        <lgl>      
#1     2 -51.6 -30.1 18932 TRUE          TRUE         NA           FALSE      
#2     3 -51.6 -30.1 18946 NA            NA           TRUE         TRUE       
#3     4 -51.6 -30.1 18946 NA            NA           FALSE        TRUE
```